# Partition $3n$ people into $n$ groups of $3$ people with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

There are $N$ number of sons, fathers and mothers. How to partition $3n$ of them into $n$ groups of $3$ people such that in each group is one son, one father and one mother but no son with his own father and mother?

Thanks in advance for giving me an approach or a hint?

Comment: Does the "OR" case count or not? That is, a son with his own father but not his mother.

Comment: there's no or. in a group, son should not be with his own mother AND his own father.

Comment: Are the groups distinguishable (i.e, switching the people in groups $x$ and $y$ makes a different solution to the problem).

Comment: So the or case does not count. Then I think you have to do the exclusion-inclusion thing. "Withuot restriction" - "son with 
 own father" - "son with own mother" + "son with both own father and own mother"

Comment: Actually nevermind. Each case has an "at least one group" in it so its not just simple exlusion-inclusion.

Comment: Actually I think it's just the number of derangements of $n$ squared. First you label each son $1$ to $n$, each mother $1$ to $n$ and each father $1$ to $n$. We arrange sons as ascending order, then arrange such that the mothers stay in derangement with sons and the fathers stay in derangement with sons and we are good.

Comment: @cr001 Thanks dude

Comment: You can have the father with the son but the mother not with the son, and the problem will still be satisfied.

Comment: @Joshua Wang That's my question in the first comment and he says that does not count.

Comment: I think he meant "the son should not be with *both* his mother and his father".

Comment: Well that's exactly what I asked in the first comment. I guess the answer is still ambiguous so please clarify.

Comment: "the son should not be with both his mother and his father", yes this is correct @cr001

Comment: So "son + his father + non-his-mother" is a legitimate group, is that correct?

Comment: @cr001 Yes, son + his father +non-his-mother is ok, son + his mother + non-his-father is also ok.

Comment: Then the number is just "all cases without restriction" - "at least one group where son is with his father and mother". The latter can be calculated using inclusion-exclusion on the number of groups. The result will look like $(n!)^2 - {n\choose 1}((n-1)!)^2 + {n\choose 2}((n-2)!)^2 -  {n\choose 3}((n-3)!)^2 + ...$.

Comment: @cr001 Thanks, I wish you posted it as an answer, sorry I was busy and I couldn't come here to thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest approach would be to start with the sons, then square the number of derangements of $N$ because each father and each mother can be with anyone *but* their own son. For instance, for $N=2$ you have one solution (the parents swap children or vice versa) and for $N=3$ you have two options for each parent-type, hence four solutions in total.

Comment: Please read the comments in the original post. son + his mother+ non-father is valid.

Comment: Sorry, that response was buried. Still, I think that starting with the sons arranged separately (e.g. numbering the groups $1,\dots,N$ by which son is there) and then **adding** the groups with one parent is likelier to be easier. Still, I'll delete or edit with credit. Actually, it looks like your response should become the answer, along with some explanation of what was meant in the original.